# Pass complex objects from thead to UI (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, event-handling, treeview

I have a `Thread` that retrieves objects from a third party `API` and stores them in a `TreeView` list `List<TreeView>`. My intention is that the `TreeView` inside the `GUI` displays the nodes, but I've had no success so far.

Since I've tried almost all kinds of `Dispatcher.Invoke` stuff, I think I need to raise an event and somehow pass the `List<TreeView>` object, but I have no clue on how to do so.
Anyhow, my goal is to update the `TreeView` from a thread different from the UI one.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm on `WPF .NET 4`.

My latest attempt:

```
private void runButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (PfUtils.isAPIConnected() && !GUIlocked) 
    {
        this.lockGUI();
        paralell_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunPowerFlowSimulation));
        paralell_thread.IsBackground = true;
        paralell_thread.Name = "RunPowerFlow";
        paralell_thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        paralell_thread.Start();
        mainTabPanel.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}

private void RunPowerFlowSimulation() 
{
    PfUtilsUtilsExtended pf = new PfUtilsUtilsExtended();
    pf.performLoadFlow(statusLabel, pgbar1);
    TreeView tv = pf.gerRelevantObjects(PfUtils.GetActiveProject(), statusLabel, pgbar1);
    tv.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { objectTreeView.ItemsSource = tv.Items; }));

    this.UnLockGUI();
}
```

Comment: Do you use something like `ObservableCollection<>` to store the data that you want to display in your treeview?

Comment: Post some code and XAML. Otherwise it's all speculations.

Comment: Note that some over the Dispatcher.Invoke stuff requires .NET 4.5 and will crash hard if run on computers without it.

Comment: @Terje - If the code is compiled against .NET 4.5 the program woudln't even run if .NET 4.5 wasn't even installed.  Besides the user is using .NET 4.0 so Dispatcher.Invoke can be used without any worries.  I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: It seems correct can u show us the XAML code.

Comment: The XAML is the standard generated by VS2012 I haven't touched it. But for the treeview is: <TreeView x:Name="objectTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="172" Margin="0,0,0,28.96" MouseDoubleClick="objectTreeView_MouseDoubleClick"/>

Comment: kind of looks to me like the Treeview tv is being created on a thread that the UI thread wouldn't be able to access in the dispatcher.invoke method next line (unless TreeView isn't the wpf treeview and is some other class)

Comment: Totally agree Andy, but as I'm new to this, How can I pass the values of tv to the UI thread?

Comment: @Ramhound Of course I know that, but sometimes people use build servers, deploy servers, and all kinds of stuff, and I had this exact problem before, except it worked wonderfully on my machine (.net 4.5), and crashed brutally without any reasonable logging on the build server (.net 4), - so I thought I'd mention it so he doesnt have to spend days worrying about that, as the question doesnt say anything about environments.

Comment: Is the method pf.gerRelevantObjects under your control? Can you pass out it's data in another form that isn't already in a user control?

Comment: @Andy Sure, anything, before this I was trying to pass a List<TreeViewItem> with the very same result, apparently you cannot easily pass complex objects, but you can change properties.

Comment: Did you try passing the list<> through the parameter of a generic action ? object data = <your data>; new Action<object>(parameter => { /*parameter contains data*/ }).BeginInvoke(data, null, null);

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the list<TreeViewItem>, the items are user controls and work the same way as the treeview

Comment: I guess if the worst comes to the worst and you can't pass the data out in a format that's not a user control you could always binary format it in to a byte array then back in to a treeview in the UI thread.

Comment: @Andy, doing what you said: {object data = <your data>; new Action<object>(parameter => { /*parameter contains data*/ }).BeginInvoke(data, null, null);} An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: At least this is some new exception... maybe this is the way

Comment: Still the same issue, you're trying to pass a control object that's already locked to a thread on to another thread, you have to get your data in a format that's not a control (serialize it or pass it out of your method in a class that doesn't derive from control)